# How to define a tuple that has a Python object?

Tags: cython

The [language docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#types) how to define a `ctuple` of regular C types, but would it be possible to mix a Python object in a `ctuple`?

Comment: What do you mean by "tuple"? Tuple is a python-object you can put a Python-object into it. Adding a link to the page of the docs your are referencing would also be beneficial...

Comment: Good point. I meant a `ctuple`. I tried defining an `cdef (object, object) x = a,b` and I get a compiler error that Python objects aren't possible in tuples yet.

Comment: I think the compiler error gives you the answer pretty definitively. You can always just use a regular tuple of course (or just not type `x`)

Comment: This is a real pity. I meant to do a Cython backend for the Spiral language, but Python objects not being composable with Cython tuples, union and structs takes away a lot of value of it for me.

Comment: I am talking about the Cython 0.29.21 here. It might be worth checking out the prerelease to see if that applies there as well.

Answer (score 1):

A `PyObject *` is a quite cumbersome thing in C: every time its value (i.e. the address of a Python-object)  is copied the reference counter must be increased and every time a `PyObject *` gets a new value (or goes out of scope) the reference counter must be decreased.

Very similar to C++ `std::shared_ptr`, only without (copy)constructor, destructor or assignment-operator being supported by C.

For a variable of type `object`, Cython manages reference count - but this doesn't work with C-structs out of the box.

So one has to fall back to `PyObject *` in a `ctuple`- the main difference between `PyObject *` and `object`, is that Cython no longer manages reference counting and thus it can be used in a  `ctuple`.

How it should be done depends on the usage of `ctuple`.

If we have a guarantee, that Python objects live longer than our `ctuple`, we don't have to care about in-/decreasing reference counter (i.e. `weak` references are enough), e.g.:

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport PyObject

cdef (PyObject *, PyObject *) create_weak(object a, object b):
    return (<PyObject *>a, <PyObject *>b) # Cython no longer manages ref-counting

def use_weak(a, b):
    cdef (PyObject *, PyObject *) p = create_weak(a,b)
    return <object>p[0], <object>p[1]   # casting to object => Cython manages ref-counting
```

However, if we must ensure that the objects live long enough, we must perform reference counting (and that can be quite error prone):

```
%%cython
from cpython cimport PyObject, Py_XINCREF, Py_XDECREF

cdef (PyObject *, PyObject *) create(object a, object b):
    cdef PyObject *a_ptr = <PyObject *>a
    cdef PyObject *b_ptr = <PyObject *>b
    Py_XINCREF(a_ptr)  # need to ensure that objects
    Py_XINCREF(b_ptr)  # stay alive as long as ctuple lives
    return (a_ptr, b_ptr)

cdef void free((PyObject *, PyObject *) p):
    Py_XDECREF(p[0])  # p will go out of scope soon
    Py_XDECREF(p[1])  # no need to keep objects alive

def use(a, b):
    cdef (PyObject *, PyObject *) p = create(a,b)
    # as long as object of p alive use them:
    res0 =  <object>p[0]
    res1 =  <object>p[1]
    # before p goes out of scope decrease ref count of objects
    free(p)
    # res0, res1 are still alive, because Cython ensured
    # it when casting to <object>
    return res0, res1
```

Another alternative would be to use C++ and to wrap `PyObject *` into a C++ which would handle the reference counting, here is a small prototype:

```
%%cython -+
from cpython cimport PyObject

cdef extern from *:
    """
    #include <Python.h>
    class PyObjectHolder{
    public:
        PyObject *ptr;
        PyObjectHolder():ptr(nullptr){}
        PyObjectHolder(PyObject *o):ptr(o){
           Py_XINCREF(ptr);
        }
        //rule of 3
        ~PyObjectHolder(){
            Py_XDECREF(ptr);
        }
        PyObjectHolder(const PyObjectHolder &h):
            PyObjectHolder(h.ptr){}
        PyObjectHolder& operator=(const PyObjectHolder &other){
            Py_XDECREF(ptr);
            ptr=other.ptr;
            Py_XINCREF(ptr);
            return *this;
        }
    };
    """
    cdef cppclass PyObjectHolder:
        PyObjectHolder(object o)
        PyObject *ptr


cdef (PyObjectHolder, PyObjectHolder) create_cpp(object a, object b):
    return (PyObjectHolder(a), PyObjectHolder(b))


def use_cpp(a, b):
    cdef (PyObjectHolder, PyObjectHolder) p = create_cpp(a,b)
    return <object>(p[0].ptr), <object>(p[1].ptr)
```

---

If using c++ is possible, then using a wrapper for `PyObject` seems to me the saner alternative.